# Very strange warning in Dart Editor. Can I disable them somehow?

Tags: javascript, dart, compiler-warnings

This small program generate this warning in Dart Editor.

This is just sample but not the real code. But real code are similar (and bigger).

```dart
void main() {
  var what_I_if_not_want_compile_to_js;
  var so_what = what_I_if_not_want_compile_to_js is double;
}
```

Warning: "When compiled to JS, this test might return true when the left hand side is an int"

P.S.

No problem. But I have 22 lines of this warnings (in "Problems" view) in one of my programs.

Can I disable them somehow?

I cannot avoid this test. Here is code from real program.

```dart
dynamic _cast(value) {
  if(value is double) {
    value = value.toInt();
  }

  if(value is int) {
    if(value >= -2147483648 && value <= 2147483647) {
      return value;
    }

    value &= 0xffffffff;
    return value <= 2147483647 ? value : value - 0x100000000;
  } else if(value is CData && value.type is ReferenceType) {
    return _cast(value._address);
  } else {
    return super._cast(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know of any way to suppress warning. However, couldn't you do `if(value is num)` instead? `toInt()` is available there, too.

Comment: @MarioP This test `if (value is num)` add the unnecessary overhead because it evaluates to `true` for `int`. So, `intValue.toInt()` is not serious. I cannot understand the following: With this warning Dart developers want to say that they not recommendet use this test even code never be compiled to Javascript? Or they want to say that every Dart code must be compiled in Javascript? I start work with old code and was very surprised with this warning.

Comment: True, but it's a performance vs. maintenance thing I guess. It's a moot point anyway, as there seems to be a solution. But as for why this warning was implemented: My guess would be that the base line of thinking was that it's better to be warned at development time instead of getting a bug that is really hard to track down after going productive. After all, there are a lot of bug reports for this long known bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn off dart2js related hints in Dart Editor by going to Tools-> Preferences -> Hints and unchecking the "Enable dart2js related hints" checkbox.

There are also plans to allow for manually suppressing certain warnings. You can follow [the issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12490).